# C#: iTextSharp, how can i edit the title property of a pdf-document?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I use the **iTextSharp** Library in my C# project to read and edit pdf documents.
Now I want to change the title of a certain pdf-document. 
I searched a lot about this issue, but nothing really works for me.
Best I found is following:

```
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(filePath);

using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(newFilePath, 
                                              FileMode.Create,
                                              FileAccess.Write))
{
    string title = pdfReader.Info["Title"] as string;
    Trace.WriteLine("Existing title: " + title);

    PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, fileStream);

    // The info property returns a copy of the internal HashTable
    Hashtable newInfo = pdfReader.Info;

    newInfo["Title"] = "New title";

    pdfStamper.MoreInfo = newInfo;

    pdfReader.Close();
    pdfStamper.Close();
}
```

But Visual Studio says that **`System.Collection.Hashtable` can't be converted implicit into `System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,string>`. There is already an existing conversion.**

Hope anyone can help me with that. Or has another solution with iTextSharp to edit the title.

Answer (score 5):

You need to change this:

```
Hashtable newInfo = pdfReader.Info;
```

To this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> newInfo = pdfReader.Info;
```

Because as the error says, `pdfReader.Info` returns a reference to a `IDictionary<string, string>`, not a `Hashtable`.

Note that if you want to modify `Info`, there's no need to create an extra local variable:

```
var title = "Title";
if (pdfReader.Info.ContainsKey(title))
{
    pdfReader.Info[title] = "NewTitle";
}
```